# Expanding a variable in a $'...'-quoted string

Tags: shell, unix, echo, vi

I am trying to append line immediately after a specific line

```
echo $'oSAMPLEINSERT\E:x\n' |vi +/"$search_string" config.txt
```

can i use a variable(for example $SampleIns) instead of hard coding the string "SAMPLEINSERT". Can someone help please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change quoting contexts in the middle of a string. (Your code is actually already doing this: `+/"$search_string"` expands the `+/` parts in an unquoted context, and `$search_string` in a double-quoted context).

Put the part that contains a variable inside double quotes, and the part that needs C-style backslash escape handling inside of `$''`, as follows:

```
echo "o${SampleIns}"$'\E:x\n'
```

If `SampleIns` contains backslash sequences, replace them with the literal values they refer to using `printf %b` beforehand:

```
printf -v SampleInsLiteral '%b' "$SampleIns"
echo "o${SampleInsLiteral}"$'\E:x\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

`ed` is probably more appropriate for a job like this. The only assumption is that `$searchstring` doesn't contain an unescaped `/`.

```
# Make sure the search value is quoted for ed.
# That means verifying that ORACLE_HOME is similarly
# escaped. E.g. ORACLE_HOME='\/usr\/foo\/bar'
searchstring="LoadModule rewrite_module \"${ORACLE_HOME}\/ohs\/modules\/mod_rewrite.so\""
ed config.txt <<EOF
/$searchstring/a
SAMPLEINSERT
.
w
EOF
```

Comment: let me give you a sample search string                                      "LoadModule rewrite_module "${ORACLE_HOME}/ohs/modules/mod_rewrite.so"            I would appreciate a solution other than vi ... vi seems little fragile